# Laravel Many models as Publisher Polymorphic Relationship with pivot?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design, eloquent

Hi I am having problems with relation and database design.

There are three tables called 'articles' , 'users' , and 'companies' with one attribute each called id:

```
"articles" -id

"users" -id

"companies" -id
```

The article table contain many publishers that are user model or company model.

My pivot table must be something similar to 'authors' -id, -model_id, -model_name, -article_id

Is there any way to get article's publisher ids and data from models in one collection with a single query? Maybe I misunderstood the problem and there is a simpler solution for that case.

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Article only have one company or one user , The right way to do that is to do a one to many (polymorphic) relationship creating the table with these columns:-
{ article_id , articleable_id , articleable_type }
and then define it in your model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning articleable models.
     */
    public function articleable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

and the Users table:-

```
class Userextends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the user's articles.
     */
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Article', 'articleable');
    }
}
```

and same in the Company model:-

```
class Company extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the companies articles.
     */
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Article', 'articleable');
    }
}
```

and then you can retrieve the relationship using:-

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->articles as $article) {
    // do this
}
```

as mentioned [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

but if the article can have more than user or company then you have to do many to many polymorphic as mentioned [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Comment: Hi, I have described the problem below

Answer (score 0):

@Mohamed Gabr
the problem is that i need this in many to many way.

and i don't have problem to receive article from User model or Company.

I need receive authors from Article.

i assume there will be something like that.

```
class Article extends Model
{

    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article_Authors','article_id');
    }
}

class Article_Authors extends Model
{

     public function authorable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function article(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }
}


class User extends Model
{

    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Article', 'authorable');
    }
}


class Company extends Model
{

    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Article', 'authorable');
    }
}
```

i can make it work but i don't think its good practice

Comment: you can try eager loading there instead, like  Article::with('user')->get(); and it should work fine in the above solution, have you tried it? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @MohamedGabr it's not working :( i describe new problem above

Comment: you're defining one to many relationship between authors and Article_Authors model, try to define the table names in the model then provide the foreign and local keys in each relation, because u r not following the naming conventions, or you can rename your table to Articles instead , that's how you can provide the local and foreign keys return $this->hasMany('App\Article', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

Answer (score 0):

I implement this models

```
class Article extends Model
{

    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article_Authors','article_id');
    }
}

class Article_Authors extends Model
{

     public function authorable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function article(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }
}


class User extends Model
{

    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Article', 'authorable');
    }
}


class Company extends Model
{

    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Article', 'authorable');
    }
}
```

and after call $article->authors i get

```
0   
id  1
record_id   2
authorable_id   1
authorable_type "App\\User"
created_at  "2019-03-22 15:56:38"
updated_at  "2019-03-22 15:56:38"
1   
id  2
record_id   2
authorable_id   1
authorable_type "App\\Company"
created_at  "2019-03-22 15:56:59"
updated_at  "2019-03-22 15:56:59"
```

how to call  this models now :(

@MohamedGabr

Edit :
after making research i didn't find any option to get result in one query there is only option to make a loop and checking instants of model.
its generate a loot loops for collection i need cache result and please settle for this temporarily.

thx For help